# Harry Potter fanfiction where Harry is given Excalibur by the Lady of the Lake

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

I am searching for a Harry Potter fanfiction with the following things in it.

Harry was imprisoned in Azkaban after being framed.

Voldemort tortures him.

Bellatrix removes one of Harry’s eyes.

Harry is Lord Emryss, Black, Potter and many more.

He is trained by the founders, the Flamels, Merlin, the knights of the roundtable and the Peverells.

Harry is given Excalibur by the Lady of the Lake.

He anulls Bellatrix and Narcissa’s marriages.

I have read it before but can’t seem to find it now

Comment: Hi welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Comment: On ao3 and last year.

Comment: Ao3 and last year